# Hosting Windows Workflow Designer

Tags: .net, workflow, hosting, workflow-foundation

Does anyone have any experience hosting the Windows Workflow designer surface? I've seen a couple of rather difficult to follow examples on MSDN, but not much else - certainly nothing that offers an explanation into the process of hosting WF that is clear or easy to read... Are there better resources out there for hosting WF (or a workflow-like design surface - I'm not necessarily tied to WF) that actually **make sense**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a reference application from MSDN if you want to learn from code.

[WF Sample Workflow Designer Visual Studio 2005 Solution](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3a331d20-44d4-4fb4-a833-f6ec9aee1b82&displaylang=en)

There was a blog maintained by the developer of the workflow designer. Will update the post as soon as I am able to dig it out.

Answer (score 2):

From the little that I have read about WF 4.0 [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/9/B/59B74A2A-245D-4304-802E-E0A0800FACD3/Dublin__NET_4_overview.docx), like:

> - Updated visual designer
>
>   - Easier to use by end-users
>   - Easier to rehost by ISVs
>   - Ability to debug XAML
> - New workflow flow-control models
>
>   - Flowcharts, rules

I suggest to wait the announcements at the PDC (end of October)

Comment: Thanks - I had no idea there was going to be a WF4. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are also a couple of books out there that describe how to host the workflow designer. For instance the Pro WF books (by Bruce Bukovics).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, rehosting the designer in WF 3.x is not super-simple, and requires you to have some understanding of the designer architecture. MS is looking at improving this in the next version (which isn't even beta yet, but they talked about this at PDC today).

Question for the questioner - Is one of the articles you mention this one?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx

I think the best hope of understanding is probably to download the code sample first and try and read it in parallel with the article.