# How can I host the Windows Workflow 4 'Workflow Designer"? Is Silverlight, or Click once supported?

Tags: silverlight, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

There is a question that references the old, buggy 3.5 version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198191/hosting-windows-workflow-designer).  This question is regarding the WF that comes with .NET 4.

My question is, where can I find a code sample and information on hosting the Workflow 4 Designer?

Is Silverlight Supported, or Click Once?  What .NET client profiles are supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several samples out there showing how to rehost the designer. [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx) is one on my blog and here is [another](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en) in the MSDN WF4 & WCF samples.

The WorkflowDesigner is a WPF control, there is no Silverlight version available. The client profile should be good enough for almost all your needs. And Click Once will work just fine.